# When does the control source save data in the database?

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-2005, vba, ms-access-2007

My question is how are control source property and afterupdate event related to each other in terms of order of occurence?Which one occurs first?
I want to  have a msgbox asking user to confirm if he would like to save the data he just entered in the textbox.The textbox has control source prpoerty set to some field.If the user cancels the action the text he entered should not get saved.
What if I put the msgbox in the OnChange event of the textbox, wouldn't it be too early to prompt the user to confirm data entry?
Note:the control source is a field of type date.

Comment: Or in the Before update event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ControlSource isn't really directly related to the Change, BeforeUpdate or AfterUpdate events.

The event you need to use is the BeforeUpdate event.

```
Private Sub txtFirstName_BeforeUpdate(Cancel as Integer)
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to save this data?", vbYesNo, "Um...") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to add that in most situations it's better to use the Form's BeforeUpdate event to validate things rather than doing it on the control's BeforeUpdate event, simply because it tends to be more user friendly. The Form's BeforeUpdate event works the same way as the code I posted above does.

Also, using MsgBox during validation routines is the way most people do it but it really isn't considered a good design practice. It would be better to have a textbox or label that you can use to output validation messages and then maybe play a sound as well so that the user knows that the data they entered isn't valid.

Comment: When the user clicks NO, I get runtime error pointing to a line of code where recalc is written.

Comment: You probably need to run your ReCalc on the AfterUpdate event. AfterUpdate will not fire if the user clicks No in the BeforeUpdate code.

Comment: ReCalc is already in the afterupdate event of the same texbox.

Comment: Also,there is another textbox txt2 which depends upon the value that is updated.txt2 is not updated immediately as the above textbox is updated.

Comment: So how is recalc being called when the user clicks no?

Comment: Well, there are certainly many cases where validating the control immediately is a good idea but I do think that using MsgBox and Cancel is not an overly good idea, with perhaps some rare exceptions.

Comment: the name of the textbox is fldManualPlandate:                    Private Sub fldManualPlandate_AfterUpdate()         Me.txt_TEMPPLANDATE = Null                                     Recalc                                                   Debug.Print Me.txt_TEMPPLANDATE                                                 Debug.Print Me.sfrmNENINSPECTIONS.Form!txt_MAXDATE                  Debug.Print Me.txt_CALCWEEK                              Debug.Print Me.TXTA_INIPLANDATE                                  End Sub

Comment: I believe ReCalc is for recalculating/updating any fields on the form that are dependent on a particular control.The functionality was working untill now.

Comment: IF I put the code in the beforeupdate event of the form,the problem with the msgbox is that it does not allow me to move to any other control untill I click yes.Whereas if I have the code in the beforeupdate event of the textbox the same thing happens but only for the textbox and not all the controls.

Comment: I have two calculated controls one of which calculates weeks for the date entered by user.I just replaced recalc by requery and it's working!Thanks a lot!I still wonder why isn't it working for ReCalc..